# Signature error when authenticating with adfs using sustainsys.saml2 package

Tags: asp.net-core, x509certificate, saml-2.0, adfs, sustainsys-saml2

I’m trying to implement ADFS SSO authentication for my ASP.NET Core app using sustainsys.saml2.

When I go to my login controller it redirects to the ADFS server and then I login via the adfs login page and get redirected back to my server. But my server throws

`"Sustainsys.Saml2.UnsuccessfulSamlOperationException": The Saml2Response must have status success to extract claims.`

(`Saml2 Status code: responder`).

I went to the ADFS server and viewed the logs, and I see the error:
`Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.XmlSignature.SignatureVerificationFailedException: MSI0037: No signature verification certificate found for issuer "<my-application-url>".`

My sustainsys configuration is:

```
options.SPOptions.EntityId = new EntityId("<my-application-url">);
options.SPOptions.PublicOrigin = new Uri("<my-application-url");
options.AuthenticaionRequestSigningBehavior = SigningBehavior.Always;
options.SPOptions.WantAssertionsSigned = true;
var certificate = new X509Certificate(certificatePath, secret);

IdentityProvider identityProvider = new IdentityProvider(
  new EntityId("http://<adfs-server>/adfs/services/trust"), options.SPOptions)
  {
      MetadataLocation = "<adfs-metadata-url>",
      AllowUnsolicitedAuthnResponse = true,
      Binding = Saml2BindingType.HttpRedirect,
      WantAuthnRequestsSigned = true,
      OutboundSigningAlogorithm = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"
   };

identityProvider.SigningKeys.AddConfiguredKey(certificate);
options.IdentityProviders.Add(identityProvider);

ServicesCertificate serviceCertificate = new ServiceCertificate()
{
  Certificate = certificate,
  Use = CertificateUse.Signing
}

options.SPOptions.ServiceCertificates.Add(serviceCertificate);
```

I’ve tried every option I could find and the error still persists

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the ADFS server with the public part of your certificate. I guess ADFS can import a .cer if you generate that from your .pfx.